# How to get status of all container pipeline in power shell?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I write script in powershell azure to get status pipeline.

- **Step 1:**  Using function `Invoke-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline` to run pipeline `SPVB_YIELD_KPI`.
- **Step 2:** Using function `Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun` to get status `SPVB_YIELD_KPI`.

It returns the status of only **SPVB_YIELD_KPI**.

How can I return all status containers in pipeline (example `[Get Metadata]`, `[ForEach]`,... in image)?

[image]

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail?

Comment: I have a pipeline SPVB_YIELD_KPI (in pipeline have multi containers, you can see in image in my post). I want to function,... to return status of all container in my piplines. I use function Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun but it only return status pipeline SPVB_YIELD_KPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the running detailsof  every activity in one pipeline, we can use the  PowerShell command [`Get-AzDataFactoryV2ActivityRun`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/get-azdatafactoryv2activityrun?view=azps-5.4.0). For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-powershell#monitor-the-pipeline-run)

For example

```
#Invoke a pipeline
$RunId = Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline `
  -DataFactoryName "<DataFactoryName>" `
  -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" `
  -PipelineName "<pipeLineName>"

# check pipeline status
while ($True) {
    $Run = Get-AzDataFactoryV2PipelineRun `
        -ResourceGroupName "<DataFactoryName>" `
        -DataFactoryName "<pipeLineName>" `
        -PipelineRunId $RunId

    if ($Run) {
        if ($run.Status -ne 'InProgress') {
            Write-Output ("Pipeline run finished. The status is: " +  $Run.Status)
            $Run
            break
        }
        Write-Output "Pipeline is running...status: InProgress"
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
} 

#  get the running details of  every activity in the pipeline
Get-AzDataFactoryV2ActivityRun `
        -ResourceGroupName "<DataFactoryName>" `
        -DataFactoryName "<pipeLineName>" `
        -PipelineRunId $RunId `
        -RunStartedAfter (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30) -RunStartedBefore (Get-Date).AddMinutes(30)
```

[image]